# Storing reference of an executable/taskhost to add precedence constraint

Tags: c#, ssis

I am programmatically creating executesql tasks in a for loop and adding it to my package. Now  the Add call returns to me an Executable collection object. I want to store these references in a dictionary with some string key name based on some uniqueness of the task that I added.

I want to do this so that when out of the for loop, I can add precedence constraints between various executable tasks after all the tasks have been formed. Is there a way to do this?

I tried creating a dictionary of string to Executable, but when adding the returned executable from the Add method, I can get an exception that the Executable is NULL.  MSDN gives an example here how to add the precedence constraints like this

```
    using System;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;

namespace Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Samples
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Package p = new Package();

      // Add a File System task.
      Executable eFileTask1 = p.Executables.Add("STOCK:FileSystemTask");
      TaskHost thFileHost1 = eFileTask1 as TaskHost;

      // Add a second File System task.
      Executable eFileTask2 = p.Executables.Add("STOCK:FileSystemTask");
      TaskHost thFileHost2 = eFileTask2 as TaskHost;

      // Put a precedence constraint between the tasks.
      // Set the constraint to specify that the second File System task cannot run
      // until the first File System task finishes.
      PrecedenceConstraint pcFileTasks = 
        p.PrecedenceConstraints.Add((Executable)thFileHost1, (Executable)thFileHost2);
      pcFileTasks.Value = DTSExecResult.Completion;
    }
  }
}
```

In my scenario, its just that the number of tasks being added is controlled dynamically and I want to store the handle for each task created so that later on I can pass those handles to the add precedence constraint func call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it to work. It works the regular expected way.

Answer (score 0):

You're connecting the wrong things. The Add is going to expect the `Executable`, not the `TaskHost`

```
PrecedenceConstraint pcFileTasks = p.PrecedenceConstraints.Add(eFileTask1, eFileTask2);
```

Using this code, I generated the following package which has the `Completion` precedence constraint between the two tasks.

[image]

Comment: The taskhost can be passed in an executable as well. The above mentioned code is taken from the MSDN website. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135956.aspx         My question is not about distinctions between taskhosts and Executable but how to keep the reference to an executable in a collection object so that it can be used later.